# How to join tables in sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js, join

I have a question on sequelize (cli). I have two tables. now I have an n:m relation. So I will need a join table. Something like this

```
zoneId | chargeId
-------+---------
1          3
4          5
```

I'm not sure how to do this in sequelize. Do I really need a new model for this? Is there any other best practice for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For storing Many to many relationships you always need a join table. You have to create a new model which will store all these mappings. Its independent of ORM you use. Many to many relationships can't be stored without a join table.

Refer [this](https://medium.com/@THEozmic/how-to-create-many-to-many-relationship-using-sequelize-orm-postgres-on-express-677753a3edb5) blog for many to many relationships in Sequelize with Postgres

https://medium.com/@THEozmic/how-to-create-many-to-many-relationship-using-sequelize-orm-postgres-on-express-677753a3edb5